# Advice for opening/handling a 580GB error log file

Tags: php, wordpress, logging, error-handling

A friend asked me to help him with a simple php script I placed on their Wordpress site. In doing so, I came across a few glaring issues I thought I could help him with. Then I came across the beast.

A 580 gigabyte error log file.

This is a simple blog, granted with millions of views a month and gigabytes of pictures, but shouldn't he do some maintenance on the thing? I know I could `tail -f` the log file in most circumstances but I think it may make planets collide trying to open a text file that large.

### Question

Should I tell him to just wipe it and start monitoring it fresh from here on out or is there a proper way to review even, say, the last 10 days worth of logs? I haven't spent enough time on their server (just browsed FTP) to see what they are running.

Comment: What is creating this log file? Obviously this logging process needs improvement in rotating/archiving/truncating log files.

Comment: 0_0  If the timestamps are easily parseable, then you might want to pound out a small script that reads through the file and only copies the last X days of data (for a reasonable value of X) to a separate file.  Then you can kill the monster log file.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on Server Fault. I also think you are more likely to get an answer if you change your question to one about opening large files, or only opening the end part of a text file.

Comment: *cough* logrotate *cough* *cough*

Comment: thanks for the advice on the title - although, guys, I know what NEEDS to be done in the future. I am simply asking about this particular file. I really don't see harm in just clearing it out for now but am curious to take a look at the beast.

Comment: Oh the SO vote to close with no explanation. Gotta love it. Any explanation or request for additional information can be commented. I am asking a perfectly legitimate question here folks.

Comment: Maybe instead of closing it, it should have been migrated to serverfault or so. Though I don't see the issue since processing this file might involve some programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the last 100 lines:

```
tail -n 100 logfile > last-100-lines.log
```

In terms of 'date', you could also:

```
cat |grep '2012-12' > all-dec.log
```

Not, the exact term to `grep` for depends on what the log file looks like. Both operations will take a little while to run. If this application is disk-intense, you could run into problems by saturating the disk since this monster is pretty large and it's very unlikely you have 600+ GB of RAM and that log file is cached in memory. ;-)

Anyway, for kicks, try `bzip2 --best logfile` and then download it and then evaluate it on localhost.

It's not pretty to work with files that large, but it should be do-able.

Comment: `grep` will still have to read through the whole file just to find the portions it's interested in, which will take a very long time.  `tail` *might* be smart enough to start at the end and move backward looking for newlines, but I don't know.

Comment: @Till - thanks for the advice, though as I mention above, using this code would have to actually open the file itself first right? Opening a file that big seems nearly impossible. Also, the ideal of downloading the file (even if bzipping it) over a T1 line makes my head hurt.

Comment: Yeah, `grep` will run through the entire file for sure. It'll take a lot more resources to process. If resources are an issue, I'd recommend downloading it before compressing it too. `bzip2` is pretty disk intense as well.

Comment: Is the traffic (~0.5 TB) a concern?

Comment: I just tried `tail` on a bunch of log files. It must be smart, it seems almost instant. Where a `cat` and `grep` are a lot slower.

Comment: I'll give -tail a shot on it. Traffic is somewhat of a consideration but I am mainly speaking about taking a couple days to download a ~ 100gb file

Comment: For what it's worth – I usually download 1 GB in something like 5 minutes. It shouldn't take days. :) It's something likely to complete over night. But that of course depends on your download speed and so on. Let me know if you need further pointers for `tail`.

Comment: @Till - Well, that implies you have achieve about ~25 Mbps download speed. I have 1.5 Mbps. Even so, it would take me 834 hours to download a file that size. So I must correct myself, it would take weeks. Hell it would take you 25 hours to download it with your connection.

Comment: assuming the log file was created sequentially, use tail to extract the last (insert sensible number here) lines, then pipe output of that to grep. e.g. tail -n 100 log file | grep '2012-12' > all-dec.log you'd obviously need to know approximately how many lines it might be and perhaps double that estimate.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this happens all over the world in billions of applications, as we speak. Log files are piling data on hard-drives, sometimes years on end and sometimes forgotten.

Although some [applications](http://apache.org) provide [mecanisms](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html) to assist in the data collection and compression of logfiles, you still have to eventually "think" that wherever you store data, it tends to pile up over the years, if the data is spread over multiple sources bits are often forgotten. This is a strange question to post on stack-overflow, but hope the answer helps.

Comment: perhaps better suited for Serverfault but I believe it is a problem many web developers, perhaps WP or PHP coders have faced so just wanted to get a range of opinions if possible. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a program that opens the file, seeks to an offset that's, say, one gigabyte less than the size of the file, and copies everything from that point onward to another file.  That way you can extract the most recent logs without incurring a huge amount of disk I/O reading *through* all the old stuff.  If you want to do filtering based on date, do it on the newer smaller file, not the original huge one.

It might also be a good idea to look at some other parts of the file just to understand *why* it's so big.  Is there a certain message that's being repeated many many times, for example?  I'd do some statistical sampling:  pick a bunch of random locations in the file and read a kilobyte or so from each.  Again, seek directly to the place you're going to read from, rather than reading everything starting from the beginning.

Comment: slightly confused. You vote to close yet provide an answer. Thanks for the advice though my programming abilities extend only into web development (namely php,js, css, html).

Comment: @JM4, I voted to move it to ServerFault, since it's offtopic here.  It should've been moved there automatically, but I guess the other voters didn't choose that option.